# Timeout when read data by NRF24L01 radio

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, timeout, read-data, radio-transmission

I'm working with NRF24L01 in python and I'm confused about reading data. I have simple function to read data for 20 seconds. There is no problem if I get some data but if there is no radio signals my program stuck on "radio.read(revc_buffer)" till it gets data. There is an option to fight this? set up some kind of timeout ?

```
def recv():
    global dictt
    radio.openWritingPipe(pipes[0])
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
    radio.startListening()
    radio.stopListening()
    radio.printDetails()
    radio.startListening()
    t_end = time.time() + 20
    while time.time() < t_end:
        pipe = [0]
        while not radio.available(pipe):
            time.sleep(1000/1000000.0)
        recv_buffer = []
        radio.read(recv_buffer)
        if recv_buffer[0] == 144:
            list_temp.append(recv_buffer)
    print(list_temp)
    return
```